# Get the ColumnHeaders from a ListView and add them to a ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, combobox

I want to get `ColumnHeaders` from the ListView and then putting them in a ComboBox. I've tried to do this with the following code:

```
 For Each i In frmMain.lvItems.Columns
        cbColumn.Items.Add(i)
    Next
```

But this code shows this ugly bit of text that says: "ColumnHeader: Text:".

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding `ColumnHeader` objects to your ComboBox, so what you see displayed in the ComboBox is `ColumnHeader.ToString()`, which [creates this kind of output](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ColumnHeader.cs,499) (.Net source code), e.g.:

```
ColumnHeader: Text: ColumnHeader1
```

Define the Type of the objects you iterate explicitly - so you won't get an `Object` Type - and specify the Property value to set, e.g., the `Text` property (or `Name` or whatever you prefer to see in the ComboBox):

```
cbColumn.Items.Clear()
For Each column As ColumnHeader In lvItems.Columns
    cbColumn.Items.Add(column.Text)
Next
```

Or, set the DataSource of your ComboBox to the Columns collection, specifying the property that provides the text to display: the `ColumnHeader.Text` (`"Text"`), the `ColumnHeader.Name` (`"Name"`), etc.:

```
cbColumn.DataSource = Nothing
cbColumn.DisplayMember = "Text"
cbColumn.DataSource = lvItems.Columns
```

Note that, in this case, each Item of the ComboBox is a `ColumnHeader` object, not a string.